# How to fix problem: gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found

Tags: linux

I'm installing mongodb

I'm trying to import public key with this: `wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.4.asc | sudo apt-key add -` (this link is from official site)

But I'm always recieving error like this: `gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.`

I tried to fix problem with: `--no-check-certificate`

But when I run code same error shows me.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: If I paste that command line onto my ubuntu 20.04 system it Just Works. Are you sure that in your environment the `wget` command is actually returning a GPG public key block?